# How can I replace button as link?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Register</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <div>
            <form:form method="post" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" commandName="userForm">
                <div style="width:240px">

                    <div>
                        <div>First Name:</div>
                        <div ><form:input path="name"/></div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Last Name:</div>
                        <div ><form:input path="surname"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>E-mail:</div>
                        <div ><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Username:</div>
                        <div ><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Password:</div>
                        <div ><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Confirm Password:</div>
                        <div ><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Country:</div>
                        <div>
                            <select>
                                <c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="countryVar">
                                <option value="${countryVar}">${countryVar}.code</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Phone numbers:</div>
                        <div>
                            <input name="deleteNumber" type="hidden" id="deleteNumber" />
                            <c:forEach var="phoneNumber" items="${userForm.phoneNumbers}" varStatus="varStatus">
                                <form:input path="phoneNumbers[${varStatus.index}]" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_eventId_deletePhoneNumber" onclick="document.getElementById('deleteNumber').value = ${varStatus.index};" value="Delete" />
                            </c:forEach>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="submit" name="_eventId_submitRegistration" value="Submit" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="submit" name="_eventId_addPhoneNumber" value="Add phone number" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div style="padding-left:5px">
                                    <button onclick="window.location='${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=cancelRegistration'">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>

        </div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

How can replace "_eventId_addPhoneNumber" and '_eventId_deletePhoneNumber" buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do it. Easiest way would be to just remove them from your GUI, add link and code the javascript.

Comment: @user612925 , <a href="javascript:doSomething()">Link</a>, then code doSomething()

Comment: I must to submit form with parameter, how I can do?

Comment: First learn about Viewstates(.Net) and posting form with javascript. To submit a form is as simple as calling a document.form.submit(), but I have an impression you need to learn  basic get, post, submit, javascript and then jquery. ASP.net makes things easier for you, but that doesn't mean you can skip javascript and basic html form submission.